# Can you use 2.5mm mono jack cables as a quick plug system in a guitar control panel?

Tags: guitar, pick-ups, wiring

I've picked up a guitar kit that has a simple solderless system for connecting the pickups to the control panel. You can see it here:

I was wondering if it's possible to use a 2.5 mm mono jacks to do the same job.

GuitarFetish do a Kwikplug system to swap pickups:
https://www.guitarfetish.com/GFS-Guitar-Pickups_c_7.html

But I thought using 2.5mm mono jacks would be even simpler. Is this possible?

Comment: IMO a crimpable quick plug is far simpler to install than wiring up male & female mono jacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the pups have only two wires emanating from them, yes, any male/female connectors will do the same job. Seen plenty of 2.5mm mono jacks, but not so many sockets which would go on the end of a sheathed wire, but don't see why they're not available. Or mount them onto the pcb.

Comment: idk outside the UK, maybe Radio Shack still have a high street presence somewhere… It's the kind of thing in the UK you could just walk into Tandy/Maplins to buy - but in the UK those type of retailers are all gone. RS is your go-to for anything like that these days - https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/av-connectors/jack-plugs-sockets/?applied-dimensions=4294876964,4294432000

Comment: @Tetsujin - haven't used RS for several years, but I reckon it's the only retail outlet for this sort of electrical goods in UK left, sadly. But it's all good quality.